# Securing Android Web Service

Tags: php, android, json, security

I am developing an Android App that makes request to my web service made in PHP. The way I get my data from the Android App is by passing a URL behind the code statically. This URL being in the code is not visible to the user. Is there any chance that my URL be revealed to the user and potentially allow that user to hack into my web service?

I've came into a solution here at StackOverflow where it was mentioned that I should use the String Resource to save my URL statically. But I've also came accross a question here that says that Resources on Android can be opened in File Manager if rooted.

If anyone could give me a tip to start on:

1. Calling a function inside PHP through a web service.

   public function getStudents() {
       //Code for getting student JSON
   }

   call function like http://mysite.com/getStudents()
2. Hide the URL for calling the web service in Android.

Comment: At some level the URL will be revealed so if it is really that big of a deal, you should put some security on your web service...

Comment: How could someone 'hack into' your web service just by having the URL?

Comment: @Supericy Im not sure to be honest, and Im currently thinking that it could be a possibility if your URL and method names in the web service are visible to someone. I might go with RSenApps suggestion.

Comment: You cannot rely on the URL staying hidden for security. Password protect the site, use HMACs, OAuth, or any other relevant authorisation/Athentification design. Anything else is inherently insecure

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want the user (*any* user who has the app) to see some data in your app, but not to be able to download it directly. This means that at the same time, you want the user to have access to the data and not have access to the data, which is obviously not possible. The content industry has tried and failed with countless DRM schemes. What you can do (and what DRM does) is make getting the data more annoying.

Users can get the URL by sniffing (intercepting) traffic. To prevent this, you should use SSL, and include an additional check to restrict the SSL certificates that will be allowed. This will prevent the user from installing his own CA on the phone and then using MitM tools to get the URL.

Then you need to hide the URL/key/whatever you use to distinguish your app from an evil user with a browser as deep in your app as possible. Certainly hide it in the code, and make sure to use ProGuard to make it harder to read.

Also, use a custom User Agent, custom HTTP headers and other fun stuff, check it server-side returning a generic error message so the attacker doesn't know how you found out he isn't using your app, and hide the code that adds these all over your app. (Some of these things can be set using static calls, so you can hide it nearly anywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WebServis extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // Web Servisimizdeki Namspace alanı
    private final String _Namspace      =   "http://tempuri.org/";
    // Web Servimizdeki Method ismi
    private final String _MethodName    =   "methodname";
    // Namspace ile Method isminin birleşimi
    private final String _Action        =   "http://tempuri.org/"+_MethodName;
    // Web Servisimizin Adresi
    private final String _Url           =   "http://"ip&or&domain"/WebService/Service.asmx";
    private String _ResultValue         =   "";
    Context context;
    EditText _birinci_sayi,_ikinci_sayi;
    String a,b;
    String TAG = "Response";
    String resultString;
    Object object=null;
    //priv JSONArrayAdapter getListView;
    private  ListView lv;
    ArrayList contactList;
    Button _btn_topla;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_servis);
        // Topla butonumuzu tanımlıyoruz.
        _btn_topla=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        // Yukarıda tanımladığımız _btn_topla butonuna tıklama olayını tanımlıyoruz.
        lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        _btn_topla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Hazırladığımız AsyncTask'ımızı çalıştırıyoruz..

                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();
            }
        });
    }
    // Arkaplanda webservis işlemlerimizi yaptığımız yer.
    // AsyncTask sınıfımızdan _WebServiceAsyncTask türetiyoruz..
    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            calculate();
            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
            showData(resultString);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute"+ resultString);
            Log.i(TAG, "Step 9");
            try {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        WebServis.this, contactList,
                        R.layout.list_order, new String[]{"name", "email",
                        "adres"}, new int[]{R.id.Name,
                        R.id.Email, R.id.Adres});
                Log.i(TAG, "Step 10");
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.i(TAG, "Step 11");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hata" + e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void calculate() {
        String SOAP_ACTION = _Action;
        String METHOD_NAME = _MethodName;
        String NAMESPACE = _Namspace;
        String URL = _Url;
        try {
            //PropertyInfo propertyInfo=new PropertyInfo();
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("TABLENAME","USER_TBL");
            Request.addProperty("COLUMNS","USERID,NAME,PASS,EPOSTA,ADRESS");
            Request.addProperty("WHERECRTR","");
            Request.addProperty("TOP","");
            Request.addProperty("COLUMN","");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            //soapEnvelope.headerOut = security; // this is an Element[] created before
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transport.debug=true;
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            //resultString1 = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            resultString =response.toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           // Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void showData(String json) {
        String jsonStr = json;
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from json: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("USER_TBL");
                // looping through All Contacts
                contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("USERID");
                    String name = c.getString("NAME");
                    String email = c.getString("EPOSTA");
                    String address = c.getString("ADRESS");
                    String pass = c.getString("PASS");
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("email", email);
                    contact.put("adres", address);
                    contact.put("pass", pass);
                    //contact.put("mobile", mobile);
                    // adding contact to contact list
                     contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net

```
 public string xLxS(string TABLENAME, string COLUMNS, string WHERECRTR, string TOP, string COLUMN)
        {
            string sonuc = "";
            DT = dataclass.SELECTSQL(TABLENAME, COLUMNS,TOP, WHERECRTR, "");
            if (DT.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                if (COLUMN != "")
                {
                    sonuc = DataTableToJsonObj(DT,TABLENAME);
                }
                else
                {
                    sonuc = DT.Rows[0][COLUMN].ToString();
                }
            }
            else if(DT.Rows.Count > 1) 
            {
                sonuc = DataTableToJsonObj(DT,TABLENAME);
            }
            return sonuc.ToString();
        }
```